# Background colour not animating on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am designing a webpage and I want to make a “Contact Us” page. I want the `.emailSelectorContainer`’s background to be animated to another colour. But it doesn’t seem to work. Here is the code;

```
$(".emailSelectionContainer").hover(function(){

        $(".mailImage").attr("src", "photos/mailHover.png");

        $(".emailSelectorContainer").animate({'backgroundColor': '#f5f5f5'},400);

    }, function(){

        $(".mailImage").attr("src", "photos/mail.svg");
        $(".emailSelectorContainer").animate({'backgroundColor': '#000'},400);

    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used)."* - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Have you tried changing the .animate to .css?

Comment: yes but that way it doesn’t have a smooth transition.

Comment: @billyonecan I've always found this weird. When using hex, hsl, or rgb values these numeric values should be able to be animated. I don't really see the problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply used @keyframes in css to solve the smooth transition.

Comment: Add comments to add more information to the question, instead of adding it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per the jQuery docs

> All animated properties should be animated to a **single numeric value**, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but **background-color** cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

`background-color` takes in either the name of a color (string), an rgb() value, an rgba() value or a hex value. It is not numeric.

What I would recommend is to use `CSS3 animations` with keyframes. Here is an example

```css
#my-div {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#my-div:hover {
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  from { background-color: #000; }
  to { background-color: #f5f5f5; }
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

Create a new animation with the `@keyframes` syntax. Inside the animation block declare properties for each step of the animation.

- Starting Step: Represented by `from` or `0%`
- Ending Step: Represented by `to` or `100%`

For each of the steps, we can declare multiple css rules separated by semicolons.

Now that we have our animation rule created, we need to apply it. Use the `:hover` pseudoselector to listen for when the mouse enters an element.

There are two properties to set here. The `animation-name` property should be set to the name of the rule we just created. The `animation-duration` property specifies how long the animation will run for, and in this case takes 0.4 seconds.

Alternatively, they can be converted to the short hand animation property.

`animation: changeColor 0.4s`